# Transfering the content of a text-file using JSON

Tags: powershell

I am trying to POST an associative array to a web-service.

I create the array and I use `Invoke-RestMethod` to POST it:

```
$LogData = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "LogText"    = "This is my Text."
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body ( $LogData | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress ) -ContentType "application/json"
```

This is working fine.
Now I want the property `LogText` to be dynamical and not static like in the example above.
I want to take the content of a text-file and therefore I use the code as above, but with `Get-Content`:

```
$LogData = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "LogText"    = Get-Content -Path $LogFile
}
```

This does not work. The text does not seem to be a String. It seems to be an object. If I have a closer look using the command `$LogData.LogText | ConvertTo-JSON`, I get an output like:

[image: Screenshot of LogText]

I did try to use the following, but this did not change the situation:

```
Get-Content -Path $LogFile -Raw
( Get-Content -Path $LogFile -Raw ).ToString()
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following lines of code did the trick:

```
$LogData = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "LogText"    = "$( Get-Content -Path $LogFile -Raw )"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $URL -Body ( $LogData | ConvertTo-JSON -Compress ) -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Most important thing was adding `charset=utf-8` to the ContentType. Without it the webservice did "sometimes" respond with "405 Method Not Allowed".

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Content` attaches some metadata to it's output, and `ConvertTo-Json` (in **Windows** PowerShell at least) serializes the attached metadata instead of treating the underlying string as just a string.

You can force `ConvertTo-Json` to treat them as strings by explicitly typing the containing array:

```
$LogData = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "LogText"    = [string[]]@( Get-Content -Path $LogFile )
}
```

For scalar string values, you can create a new string using `""`:

```
$LogData = @{
    "MyProperty" = "bla bla";
    "LogText"    = "$( Get-Content -Path $LogFile -Raw )"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it looks more like a string now, but it is still not working. I don't know how to debug it. Taking a statical string is working fine :-(

Comment: @DukeDonnovan What happens? Any error messages from `Invoke-RestMethod`? I can't see your screen :-)

Comment: Sorry :-) I get the status code "405 Method Not Allowed" back.